# What exact processes occur under the hood when you tap an app icon on a phone?

Tags: android, input, operating-system

I've found quite a few resources online for how this works on a laptop.

Clicking on the icon sends a request to Windows to look through its file system for the executable. Windows then looks at the app's attributes and permissions to determine whether it should be opened.
Once this is confirmed, APP.exe is then loaded into Random Access Memory through mapping and paging.  It also involves reading binary from it and loading in associated resources such as dll files etc etc

Is this pretty much the same for Android? If not, how is it different and if so, could you provide more detail or some resources where I can find this info?

I've found quite a few verifiable resources online for how this works on a laptop, but not for a phone (Android). I've also GPT'd it but that doesn't seem to be the most reliable. I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: See: https://medium.com/android-news/android-application-launch-explained-from-zygote-to-your-activity-oncreate-8a8f036864b